# Can't assign bigdecimal to a field in model

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, bigdecimal

```
[1] BigDecimal
BigDecimal < Numeric
[2] account.outstanding_balance = BigDecimal.new(0.3, 2)
0.3
[3] account.outstanding_balance
0
```

I cannot figure out why I am unable to assign `account.outstanding_balance` a decimal value of `.3`.

This is a rails app using mysql. The column `outstanding_balance` is decimal type.

Rails v3.2

Comment: could you add the contents of your `db/schema.rb`? Specifically the part dealing with the `Account` table.

Comment: Yup, just answered my own question. See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
t.decimal  "outstanding_balance", :precision => 10, :scale => 0
```

> **Scale** Defines the scale for the decimal fields, representing the
>   number of digits after the decimal point.

So this was lame. A migration with:

```
create_table :account do |t|
  t.decimal :outstanding_balance
end
```

Will automatically populate `schema.rb` with the above code.